# Cache locality of an array and amortized complexity

Tags: arrays, caching, memory, linked-list

An array is usually faster in access than a linked list.
This is primarily due to cache locality of an array.
I had two doubts :

1. On what factor does the amount of data that is brought into the cache memory depend ? Is it completely equal to the cache memory of the system ? How can we know what amount of memory is this ?
2. The first access to an array is usually costlier as the array has to be searched for in the memory and brought in the memory. The subsequent operations are comparitively faster. How do we calculate the amortized complexity of the access operation ?
3. What are cache misses ? Does it mean (in reference to linked list) that the required item which is needed (current pointer-> next) has not been loaded into the cache memory and hence memory has to be searched again for its address ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reality, it is a bit more complex than the simple model you present in the question.

First, you may have multiple caching layers (L1,L2,L3), each of them with different characteristics. Especially, the replacement policy for each cache may use different algorithms as a tradeoff between efficiency and complexity (i.e. cost).

Then, all modern operating-systems implement virtual memory mechanisms. It is not enough to cache the data and the instructions (which is what L1..L3 are used for), it is also required to cache the association between virtual and physical addresses (in the TLB, transaction lookaside buffer).

To understand the impact of locality, you need to consider all these mechanisms.

**Question 1**

The minimum unit exchanged between the memory and a cache is the cache line. Typically, it is 64 bytes (but it depends on the CPU model). Let's imagine the caches are empty.

If you iterate on an array, you will pay for a cache miss every 64 bytes. A smart CPU (and a smart program) could analyze the memory access pattern and decide to prefetch contiguous blocks of memory in the caches to increase the throughput.

If you iterate on a list, the access pattern will be random, and you will likely pay a cache miss for each item.

**Question 2**

The whole array is not searched and brought in the cache on first access. Only the first cache line is.

However, there is also another factor to consider: the TLB. The page size is system dependent. Typical value is 4 KB. The first time the array will be accessed, an address translation will occur (and its result will be stored in the TLB). If the array is smaller than 4 KB (page size), no other address translation will have to be done. If it is bigger, than one translation per page will be done.

Compare this to a list. The probability that multiple items fits in the same page (4 KB) is much lower than for the array. The probability that they can fit in the same cache line (64 bytes) is extremely low.

I think it is difficult to calculate a complexity because there are probably other factors to consider. But in this complexity, you have to take in account the cache line size (for cache misses), and the page size (for TLB misses).

**Question 3**

A cache miss is when a given cache line is not in the cache. It can happen at L1, L2, or L3 levels. The higher level, the more expensive.

A TLB miss occurs when the virtual address is not in the TLB. In that case, a conversion to a physical address is done using the page tables (costly) and the result is stored in the TLB.

So yes, with a linked list, you will likely pay for a higher number of cache and TLB misses than for an array.

**Useful links:**

- Wikipedia article on caches in CPUs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache
- Another good article on this topic: http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/188776-how-l1-and-l2-cpu-caches-work-and-why-theyre-an-essential-part-of-modern-chips
- An oldish, but excellent article on the same topic: http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2002/07/caching/
- A gallery of various caching effects: http://igoro.com/archive/gallery-of-processor-cache-effects/